# How to check if file was downloaded completely via Spring Rest Api

Tags: java, spring, rest, hadoop

I have created simple rest api to serve files from hdfs (Files are large and I don't want to copy them locally).

I would like to log information that file download completed successfully i.e. whole stream was read, but I do not know how. I can only log information that file download was started.

I will appreciate any help.

```
    @Autowired
    private FileDownloadService fds;

    @RequestMapping(value = GET_FILE_PATH, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity getFileStream(@RequestParam("name") String name) {
        LOG.info("Processing for filename: " + name);
        try {
            Path p = fds.getFilePath(name);
            org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream is = fds.getFileStream(p);

            return ResponseEntity.ok().header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + p.getName() + "\"'").contentLength(fds.getFileLength(p))
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).body(new InputStreamResource(is));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Internal Server Error");
        } finally {
           LOG.info("File: " + name + " download started");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to create a wrapper over InputStream and trigger some flag on stream closing (`close()`).

For instance you can take [`ProxyInputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/input/ProxyInputStream.html) as a basis:

```
 ProxyInputStreamis = new ProxyInputStream(fds.getFileStream(p)) {
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
            super.close();
            // some trigger
    }
 };
```

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you. But I still don't know how to differentiate that file was downloaded completely or for example operation was aborted.

Comment: The `ProxyInputStream` has an implementation `CountingInputStream` - you can use this one and compare file size with number of read bytes in the `close()` method